# Squared distance from the mean monotonicity

Tags: analysis, inequality

Let $S = \{ x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ be a set of say real numbers and $\mu(S) = \sum_{x \in S} x/|S|$ be the average of numbers in $S$. We define the total squared distance of each element in $S$ to $\mu(S)$ as follows:

$$L(S) = \sum_{x \in S} (x - \mu(S))^2$$.

Now, for any $S' \subset S$, is it always true that

$$L(S') \leq L(S).$$

I think this is quite intuitive but I wonder if that's the case. If so, I wonder if there is a simple proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed true. Suppose that $n\ge 1$ and $m\ge 0$ and $S_{1} = \left(x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}\right)$ and $S_{2} = \left(x_{1},\ldots,x_{n},x_{n+1},\ldots, x_{n+m}\right)$, with $\mu_{i}$ being the mean of $S_{i}$ for $i=1,2$. We want to show that $L(S_{2})\ge L(S_{1})$.

We have
$$
\begin{align*}
L(S_{2}) &= \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n+m}\left(x_{k} - \mu_{2}\right)^{2} \\
&= \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\left(x_{k} - \mu_{2}\right)^{2} + \sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{n+m}\left(x_{k} - \mu_{2}\right)^{2}.
\end{align*}
$$
Now, observe that $\left(x_{k}-\mu_{2}\right)^{2} = \left(x_{k}-\mu_{1} + \mu_{1}-\mu_{2}\right)^{2} = \left(x_{k}-\mu_{1}\right)^{2} + 2\left(x_{k} - \mu_{1}\right)\left(\mu_{1}-\mu_{2}\right) + \left(\mu_{1}-\mu_{2}\right)^{2}$. Putting this into the above, we have
$$
\begin{align*}
L(S_{2}) &= \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\left(\left(x_{k}-\mu_{1}\right)^{2} + 2\left(x_{k} - \mu_{1}\right)\left(\mu_{1}-\mu_{2}\right) + \left(\mu_{1}-\mu_{2}\right)^{2}\right) + \sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{n+m}\left(x_{k} - \mu_{2}\right)^{2}\\
&= \underbrace{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\left(x_{k}-\mu_{1}\right)^{2}}_{L(S_{1})} + 2\left(\mu_{1}-\mu_{2}\right)\underbrace{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\left(x_{k}-\mu_{1}\right)}_{=0} + n\left(\mu_{1}-\mu_{2}\right)^{2}+ \sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{n+m}\left(x_{k} - \mu_{2}\right)^{2}\\
&= L(S_{1}) + n\left(\mu_{1}-\mu_{2}\right)^{2} + \sum\limits_{k=n+1}^{n+m}\left(x_{k} - \mu_{2}\right)^{2}\\
&\ge L(S_{1}),
\end{align*}
$$
as required.

Comment: Splendid. Seems correct to me. Many thanks!